# I'm getting a 403 error when pushing to AWS CodeCommit from Windows. Git doesn't prompt for credentials. How can I fix this?

Tags: git

I encountered an Error 403 when trying to push to a Git repository on AWS CodeCommit from my Windows machine. Git did not pop up the credential manager for me to input my username and password, seemingly because it believes it already has them.

I've used this repo before, but deleted the username and password from IAM.

Comment: HTTP 403 indicates that the credentials themselves are correct - the problem is that those credentials are for an account that doesn't have permission to do what you've requested. (HTTP 401 would indicate invalid or missing credentials.)

Comment: "The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to 401, but for the 403 Forbidden status code, re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Answer (score 0):

**Open Windows Credential Manager:**

- Press Windows + R to open the Run dialog.
- Type control keymgr.dll and press Enter to open the Windows Credential Manager.

**Locate and Delete the Stored Git Credentials:**

- Under "Windows Credentials", you'll find the credentials related to Git or AWS CodeCommit. They might be labeled something like git:https://[your-repo-url] or simply have references to AWS or CodeCommit.
- Click on the relevant entry.
- Click the "Remove" or "Delete" option.

**Retry the Git Operation:**

- Now, when you try to push (or any operation that requires authentication) to the repo again, it should prompt you with the Git Credential Manager to enter your username and password.
  Remember to provide the correct credentials when prompted, and they should get stored for future operations until they change again.

Remember to provide the correct credentials when prompted, and they should get stored for future operations until they change again.